# Graph API which permission for URL

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am reimplemnting some old server side code using ruby with gem `Koala`. The old app makes a call to :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/music?method=GET&metadata=true&format=json&access_token=
```

I am confused about

1- What is the Facebook permission called that the app needs to use this URL

2- What is the object name? i am using Koala: https://github.com/arsduo/koala and it uses get_object method and requires a string. I am not sure what to pass in. "music" doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: using **me**, you are declaring that are using the default user logged in at the moment.

Comment: You need the `user_likes` permission according to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/). I can't help you with Ruby.

Comment: @eLRuLL I use me to get user's name, email, etc. But I need to access their fav artists, and the old code uses that URL.

Comment: BTW, you're using Graph API, not FQL in that query.

Comment: Yes, Edit your question please, this is not FQL, but Graph API